# SQLite on a fragment

Tags: android, sqlite

i'm trying to make a simple SQLite on my android project for some work.
`(this,null, null,null 1)` line with MyDBHandler() in MyDBHandler cannot be applied to this.
I have a feeling this to due to this being a fragment instead of the usual activity. Any ideas?

```
package com.test.test.sql;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MemoFragment extends Fragment {

    EditText Input;
    TextView LyricText;
    MyDBHandler dbHandler;
    Button addButtonClicked;
    Button deleteButtonClicked;

    public MemoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_memo, container, false);

        Input = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.Input);
        LyricText = (TextView) getView().findViewById (R.id.LyricText);
        dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
        printDatabase ();
    }
    //add lyric to database
    public void addButtonClicked(View view){
        Lyrics lyrics = new Lyrics(Input.getText().toString());
        dbHandler.addLyric(lyrics);
        printDatabase();
    }

    //delete items
    public void deleteButtonClicked(View view){
        String inputText = Input.getText().toString());
        dbHandler.deleteLyrics(inputText);
        printDatabase();
    }

    public void printDatabase(){
        String dbString = dbHandler.databasetoString();
        LyricText.setText(dbString);
        Input.setText("");
    }

}
```

Comment: where is the `addLyrics()` method defined?

Comment: @BobMalooga It is defined in MyDBHandler. I fixed that error it needed to be `addLyric()` instead of `addLyrics()` I feel the main issue is that `findViewById`  doesnt seem to work within a fragment

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with `findViewById()`. Which works perfectly inside Fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(getActivity(),null,null,1);
```

Comment: That seems to have done it Thank You for helping out

Answer (score 1):

Your onCreateView is wrong. When you place return in that position, the below lines wont be executed. So, first put the inflated layout on an View variable. then use it to instantiate the edittext and the textview. see this code below

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_memo, container, false);

    Input = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.Input);
    LyricText = (TextView) v.findViewById (R.id.LyricText);
    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
    printDatabase ();
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, im still getting errors on `dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);` the log says `error: incompatible types: MemoFragment cannot be converted to Context`